# Why isn't custom sidebar panel not showing up in the Gutenberg Editor?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, block-editor

I am trying to add a custom Gutenberg sidebar panel but it isn't showing up. I'm not sure why though as I have the sidebar.js and then enqueue it in PHP. I ran `npm run start` and it compiled the JSX into JS and then I enqueued the JS file in the `build` folder.

**init.php:**

```
<?php

add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', function() {

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'global-page-settings',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/build/index.js',
        array( 'wp-edit-post', 'wp-element', 'wp-components', 'wp-plugins', 'wp-data' )
    );

});
```

Then I add it into my `functions.php` file:

```
/**
 * Load Gutenberg settings
 * 
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/gutenberg/init.php';
```

Comment:  `sidebar.js` contains JSX/react components, you can't include it directly as the browser doesn't understand it! You need a build tool to compile it into native javascript, that's what things like WP Scripts and the block scaffolding tool were created for. Look at your browsers dev console and you should see it breaking since it doesn't understand what `import` is or why there are tags like `<PluginSidebar` in the JS file

Comment: you should read this which has using the create-block tool as the first step https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/getting-started/create-block/, while creating blocks without JSX or build tools is possible, the syntax becomes much harder and less readable, especially when most examples use JSX!

Comment: @TomJNowell View updated question. I compiled the JSX and then enqueued the index.js from the build folder. Inside of the index.js file. This file has the compiled sidebar code but it si still not working

Comment: Are you seeing any 404s in the console? Is this coming from a theme or a plugin? Can you provide the JS you're using as well?

Comment: You should keep the JS in your question, editing it out might have hidden the problem. Again though, check your browsers dev tool console for errors and 404's